# Same user multiple times - Sharing & Permissions

Tags: macos, permission, network-user

My account at work (rtonneyck), is a Windows domain account. That's what I use to login too. I noticed the permissions for my Shared windows drive has my user name listed multiple times. Why is this?? Is this a bug with Mavericks?

Screenshot: [image]

MacBook Pro with Retina display, OS X Mavericks (10.9.4), Using Windows domain

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  My own OS X workstation is bound to Active Directory and I use a network account, but I'm not understanding your issue.  Picture or example output? (make sure you hide any sensitive info!)

Comment: That is a Windows function

Comment: Added a screenshot. Sorry was on mobile at the time and couldn't add one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there are multiple entries with your user account in the [access control list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) of the share.

Unless you're experiencing performance/functionality issues, I recommend contacting the person who administers that share, letting them know about what you found, then ignore it. :)

If you're experiencing performance/functionality issues, find out if anyone else who uses the share experiences the same symptoms, compile your findings, then submit them to the share administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll get my IT admin to remove the extras.